# The set of piecewise linear functions is dense in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],X)$ with the compact-open topology and uniform topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am asked to prove that the set of piecewise linear functions is dense in $\mathcal{C}([0,1],X)$ with the compact-open topology and uniform topology. Here $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Literally I have no idea how to do it. Any help please?

Comment: What comes to your mind when I ask "how can you approximate a continuous function using piecewise linear continuous functions?" Where do you get stuck when you try to make this formal?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I am very new to this branch of mathematics so I do need help. None of my textbooks cover the relevant things. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I suppose $X$ is some metric space, but for simplicity you can just think about $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. Have you seen the theorem "continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous"? The two topologies are the same in this case, by the way

Comment: @Kushi Oh I forgot to mention that $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.